# Design a generic IR remote interface

Tags: lirc

Im wondering if it is possible to design an interface that can auto-determine which lirc.conf to use.

Currently, Im using a Raspberry Pi to control my TV by using the specific lirc.conf for my TV remote.

Now if I put the device in a different area with a different TV, how could I determine which conf to use?

Let's say we know some basic information like the brand of the TV, is there any potential to create a combined lirc that would work for all models of that brand?

Comment: This has little to no relevance to the Raspberry Pi.  I suggest you look at the generic remote controls which can be programmed for multiple devices.  If you see how they work you should get the idea.

Comment: I'm actually currently working on almost the exact same setup.  My solution is to determine the Wifi network that I'm connected to.  However, this wouldn't work with different TVs near the same WiFi network

Comment: This is probably more appropriate to our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  I would guess those generic remotes have a small database of sorts with all the commands used by Acme, Foobar, etc.  I also suspect this is made silly by all the manufacturers, including those of the generic ones, not sharing their codes despite the fact they would be relatively easy to reverse engineer (with the right equipment...).